# XPath expression with white space in node for defiant.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xpath

I am using [defiant.js](http://www.defiantjs.com/) for searching a json. According to their documentation, I need to provide xpath for searching a specific element from json. I am successful with it when there is no white space in the node. But my json now contain white space. Here is my csv. I want to get an item with specific certificate number.

```
    [
  {
    "Certificate Number":1019174,
    "Last Name":"MA",
    "First Name":"SHI",
    "Title":"MR",
    "DOB":"1/28/1990",
    "Address":"75 LEYLAND HOUSE",
    "City":"London",
    "Postal Code":"E14 0BU",
    "Country":"UK",
    "Passpot Number":"E0438750",
    "Course Level":7,
    "Course Details":"POST GRADUATE DIPLOMA IN INTERNATIONAL COMMERCIAL LAW",
    "Course Start Date":"2/2/2014",
    "Course End Date":"2/23/2015",
    "Note":"RPL Route Entry",
    "Remarks":""
  },
  {
    "Certificate Number":101235,
    "Last Name":"UD",
    "First Name":"HAN",
    "Title":"MR",
    "DOB":"1/28/1990",
    "Address":"75 LEYLAND HOUSE",
    "City":"London",
    "Postal Code":"E14 0BU",
    "Country":"UK",
    "Passpot Number":"E0438750",
    "Course Level":7,
    "Course Details":"POST GRADUATE DIPLOMA IN INTERNATIONAL COMMERCIAL LAW",
    "Course Start Date":"2/2/2014",
    "Course End Date":"2/23/2015",
    "Note":"RPL Route Entry",
    "Remarks":""
  }
]
```

My xpath was

```
//[Certificate Number="101234"]
```

When the property name is like CertificateNumber I have no problem to find the item. But with space between certificate and number I can't get the item. So how can I get an item with specific certificate number from this json. any alternative solution other than defiant.js can do.

Comment: XPath is a language for navigating _XML_ - not JSON. To navigate JSON, you'd have to use JSONPath.

Comment: Can you give me a solution on what i am facing using defiant.js

Comment: Hm, interesting. `//[Certificate Number="101234"]` is not a valid XPath expression and I doubt it works for `CertificateNumber ` (the one without whitespace). Please show the XPath expression that works for `CertificateNumber `, as you have claimed.

Comment: //*[CertificateNumber="101234"] ... this is the expression. I also removed the space of Certificate Number from the json file.. Then it works fine as no space both in json and xpath.

Comment: Fine, please try `//*[*[translate(name(),' ','') = 'CertificateNumber'] ="101234"]` - if that does not work, I suggest you use JSONPath instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the JSON properties which are invalid as XML node name (because they contain space), they are getting converted to an XML attribute in namespace by defiant.js.

For example, this part of your JSON.. :

```
{
    "Certificate Number":101235,
    "Last Name":"UD",
    "First Name":"HAN",
    "Title":"MR",
    "DOB":"1/28/1990",
    "Address":"75 LEYLAND HOUSE",
    "City":"London",
    "Postal Code":"E14 0BU",
    "Country":"UK",
    "Passpot Number":"E0438750",
    "Course Level":7,
    "Course Details":"POST GRADUATE DIPLOMA IN INTERNATIONAL COMMERCIAL LAW",
    "Course Start Date":"2/2/2014",
    "Course End Date":"2/23/2015",
    "Note":"RPL Route Entry",
    "Remarks":""
  }
```

..getting converted to the following XML structure (only relevant part of the XML posted here) :

```
<d:item xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:mi="34">
   <d:name d:name="Certificate Number" d:constr="Number" d:mi="18">101235</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="Last Name" d:constr="String" d:mi="19">UD</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="First Name" d:constr="String" d:mi="20">HAN</d:name>
   <Title d:constr="String" d:mi="21">MR</Title>
   <DOB d:constr="String" d:mi="22">1/28/1990</DOB>
   <Address d:constr="String" d:mi="23">75 LEYLAND HOUSE</Address>
   <City d:constr="String" d:mi="24">London</City>
   <d:name d:name="Postal Code" d:constr="String" d:mi="25">E14 0BU</d:name>
   <Country d:constr="String" d:mi="26">UK</Country>
   <d:name d:name="Passpot Number" d:constr="String" d:mi="27">E0438750</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="Course Level" d:constr="Number" d:mi="28">7</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="Course Details" d:constr="String" d:mi="29">POST GRADUATE DIPLOMA IN INTERNATIONAL COMMERCIAL LAW</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="Course Start Date" d:constr="String" d:mi="30">2/2/2014</d:name>
   <d:name d:name="Course End Date" d:constr="String" d:mi="31">2/23/2015</d:name>
   <Note d:constr="String" d:mi="32">RPL Route Entry</Note>
   <Remarks d:constr="String" d:mi="33"/>
</d:item>
```

So according to the XML structure, this is one possible XPath to get above element by "Certificate Number" value :

```
//*[*[@*="Certificate Number" and .=101235]]
```

Comment: An interesting library, I have to say. +1.

Comment: can you please explain your xpath a little? it would be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

With JSONPath you should be able to use

```
//Certificate Number="101235"
```

No need for `[]`