# Using XPath to exclude attributes possible?

Tags: json, xpath

I have this data and I want to be able to show only name and IP in the each node:

```
  {
    "virtualservers": [
      {
        "name": "/partition/name",
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": "80",
        "defaultpool": "",
        "sslprofile": "None",
        "compressionprofile": "/Common/cmpprof",
        "persistence": "None",
        "irules": [
          "/Common/http-to-https"
        ],
        "pools": null,
        "sourcexlatetype": "None",
        "sourcexlatepool": "None",
        "loadbalancer": "MYLB"
      },
      {
        "name": "/partition/name2",
        "ip": "2.2.2.2",
        "port": "80",
        "defaultpool": "",
        "sslprofile": "None",
        "compressionprofile": "/Common/cmpprof",
        "persistence": "None",
        "irules": [
          "/Common/anotherrule"
        ],
        "pools": null,
        "sourcexlatetype": "None",
        "sourcexlatepool": "None",
        "loadbalancer": "MYLB2"
      }
    ]
 }
```

I poked around a bit and this almost works:

```
//virtualserver[(position() > 0 and position() < 10)]/*[name()="name" or name()="ip"]

[
  "/partition/name",
  "1.1.1.1",
  "/partition/name2",
  "2.2.2.2"
]
```

But I want to keep the node information to I can step through it correctly in my templates. Ideally the result would be something like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "/partition/name",
    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  },
  {
    "name": "/partition/name2",
    "ip": "2.2.2.2",
  }
]
```

I am using defiantjs for this so it might not be fully compatible with XPath. Any suggestions welcome!

/Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using XPath. I [had experimented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972077/xpath-expression-with-white-space-in-node-for-defiant-js/28978173#28978173) a bit in the past to see how defiantjs work, basically, each item in `virtualservers` array is getting converted to single XML element, roughly like the following :

```
<d:item xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:mi="34">
   <name d:constr="String" d:mi="21">/partition/name</name>
   <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="22">1.1.1.1</ip>
   <port d:constr="String" d:mi="23">80</port>
   <defaultpool d:constr="String" d:mi="24"></defaultpool>
   <sslprofile d:constr="String" d:mi="25">None</sslprofile>
   <compressionprofile d:constr="String" d:mi="26">/Common/cmpprof</compressionprofile>
   .....
</d:item>
```

Now in XPath data model, one element is considered a unit, starting from the opening tag all the way to the corresponding closing tag. Here you want to return `item` element containing only `name` and `ip` elements like shown below, but, *there is no such element* in the source XML which XPath can return :

```
<d:item xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:mi="34">
   <name d:constr="String" d:mi="21">/partition/name</name>
   <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="22">1.1.1.1</ip>
</d:item>
```

Comment: Thak you, much appreciated!